# SETI message received

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

At 03:39:18 UTC, the Allen Telescope Array detected a series of distinct signals from the direction of the Procyon star system.  There is speculation that these signals considered together could carry an encoded message, although the encoding/decoding mechanism is not understood.  SETI is calling upon citizen scientists and the general public to put forth their ideas.

See below for an approximate visual depiction of the series, followed by a precise mathematical description.

**Approximate visual depiction:**

[image: SETI_message_received_visual_depiction]

**Mathematical description:**

```
A continuous waveform matching sin(sqrt(t)) where t varies over the range 0 to 6672 ps (picoseconds)

A pause of 135 ps, followed by 12 "E" pulses spaced every 341.8181818 ps

A pause of 345 ps, followed by 6 "N" pulses spaced every 165 ps

A pause of 323 ps, followed by 6 "O" pulses spaced every 64.8 ps

A pause of 1614 ps, followed by 5 "R" pulses spaced every 909.75 ps

A pause of 606 ps, followed by 5 "T" pulses spaced every 1304.5 ps

A pause of 2469 ps, followed by 4 "D" pulses spaced every 777.3333333 ps

A pause of 13 ps, followed by 4 "H" pulses spaced every 911.6666667 ps

A pause of 984 ps, followed by 3 "A" pulses spaced every 128 ps

A pause of 1565 ps, followed by 3 "S" pulses spaced every 1837.5 ps

A pause of 2877 ps, followed by 2 "I" pulses spaced every 2842 ps

A pause of 278 ps, followed by 2 "L" pulses spaced every 5423 ps

A pause of 659 ps, followed by 2 "W" pulses spaced every 3978 ps

A pause of 792 ps, followed by a single "C" pulse

A pause of 4340 ps, followed by a single "F" pulse

A pause of 2636 ps, followed by a single "G" pulse

A pause of 250 ps, followed by a single "K" pulse

A pause of 3669 ps, followed by a single "M" pulse

A pause of 5115 ps, followed by a single "P" pulse

A pause of 1674 ps, followed by a single "Y" pulse
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the pulse positions and

> apply the sine sweep function, then sort by the resulting values.

For example:

> There are 12 `E`s starting at t=135 and spaced by 341.818: that is, t=135, 476.818, 818.636, ... 3895. Applying the function sin(sqrt(t)) yields -0.811912, 0.154362, -0.331118, ... -0.409511. We repeat the process for each letter, and sort the resulting list, keeping track of which letter each number is associated with.

I get the following result:

> [image]

Which results in the answer:

> `THEWHOLEMOONANDTHEENTIRESKYAREREFLECTEDINONEDEWDROPONTHEGRASS`, i.e. "The whole Moon and the entire sky are reflected in one dewdrop on the grass"

Comment: Yes, the function acts as a mapping from one dimension (t) to another dimension (y) which reorders everything and suddenly it all makes sense.  Like the [Ames chair illusion](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Adelbert-Ames-Jnrs-chair-demonstration-taken-from-Ittelson-1952-p27-from-a_fig1_258821853)